# In HTML, why cant i move to new_url after clicking the login button. For the code given below

Tags: html, post, button, authentication

```
<div class="login">
            <form action="/new_url" method="POST">
            <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="user"><br>
            <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password"><br>

                <input type="button" value="Login">
```

input class is declared.
the problem is the even though the button is clickable,i cant get it to open new_url.

Comment: Maybe you have some JS that has preventDefault() on the submit to handle the form submission via AJAX. Can you post the JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to mention input type submit.
try below code

```
<div class="login">
            <form action="/new_url" method="POST">
            <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="user"><br>
            <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password"><br>

                <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<input type="submit" value="Login">`

instead of

```
<input type="button" value="Login">
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add one more input value

```
<input type="Submit" value="login">
```